# how to solve this fuction problem about string

Tags: python

```
    num1 = input("First natural number: ")
    if num1.isdigit():
        int(num1)
        break
while True:
    num2 = input("Second natural number: ")
    if num2.isdigit():
        int(num2)
        break
if num1 > num2:
    max = num1
    min = num2
elif num1 < num2:
    max = num2
    min = num1
else:
    print("%d & %d highest common division: %d",num1,num2,num1)
def tgcd(max,min):
    if max% min != 0:
        tgcd(max, min-1)
    else:
        print("%d & %d highest common division: %d",max,min,min)
tgcd(max,min)
```

when implement this code, face type error : not all arguments converted during string formatting... but i'm not use string ;;;

Comment: "but i'm not use string" I don't understand. What do you think `string` means? What kind of thing do you think, for example, `"%d & %d highest common division: %d"` is?

Comment: There are many things wrong with this code. I suggest to follow a tutorial from start to finish, and talk to an instructor or tutor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the improper use of formatting in your `print` statements.

i.e.

```
    print("%d & %d highest common division: %d",num1,num2,num1)
```

Should really be:

```
    print("%d & %d highest common division: %d" % (num1,num2,num1))
```

Ditto with the other statement.  So it should finally be:

```
while True:
    num1 = input("First natural number: ")
    if num1.isdigit():
        num1 = int(num1) # CHANGED
        break

while True:
    num2 = input("Second natural number: ")
    if num2.isdigit():
        num2 = int(num2) # CHANGED
        break

if num1 > num2:
    max = num1
    min = num2
elif num1 < num2:
    max = num2
    min = num1
else:
    print("%d & %d highest common division: %d" % (num1,num2,num1))


def tgcd(max,min):
    if max% min != 0:
        tgcd(max, min-1)
    else:
        print("%d & %d highest common division: %d" % (max,min,min))


tgcd(max,min)
```

Comment: While this is correct, i think using f-strings will be easier

Comment: "Your problem stems from the improper use of formatting in your print statements." This fixes the output, but has nothing to do with the reported error. That was fixed by the `num1 = int(num1)` etc. changes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel True.  The issue I saw was that it was an output issue.  The type issue was another item...   should fix the code.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`int()` does not modify in place. Modifying your code to:

```py
while True:
    num1 = input("First natural number: ")
    if num1.isdigit():
        num1 = int(num1) # CHANGED
        break
while True:
    num2 = input("Second natural number: ")
    if num2.isdigit():
        num2 = int(num2) # CHANGED
        break
if num1 > num2:
    max = num1
    min = num2
elif num1 < num2:
    max = num2
    min = num1
else:
    print("%d & %d highest common division: %d",num1,num2,num1)
def tgcd(max,min):
    if max% min != 0:
        tgcd(max, min-1)
    else:
        print("%d & %d highest common division: %d",max,min,min)
tgcd(max,min)
```

resolves this problem -- the code has other issues, but this fix fixes that.

Comment: The string formatting would not care if the value is actually an int. Edit: ah, I see: the problem is at `max % min`, not any of the `print`s with `%` codes in them.

Answer (score 0):

Where the code says:

```
if max% min != 0:
```

At this point, `max` **is a string**, because `num1` and `num2` are both strings, because e.g. `int(num1)` **did not change* `num1`. You cannot change a string into an integer "in-place" in Python. `int()` **creates a new** integer. If you want to use it, assign it back to the variable: `num1 = int(num1)`.

Because `max` was a string, `max % min` means to use %-style string formatting. This did not work, because the `max` string does not have any %-code in it to be replaced.

On the other hand:

```
print("%d & %d highest common division: %d",num1,num2,num1)
```

This **does not** use %-style string formatting, even though there are %-codes in the first string. That is because there is no use of the `%` operator. Instead, `num1, num2, num1` are just more arguments for the `print` function. We can fix this like: `print("%d & %d highest common division: %d" % (num1, num2, num1))`.

However, it is easier to use the modern, up-to-date approach to string formatting. It looks like this: `print(f"{num1} & {num2} highest common division: {num1}")`. Notice carefully the `f` before the `"` - that is necessary. Before the code runs, Python will transform that into `print("{} & {} highest common division: {}".format(num1, num2, num1))`, using the new `.format` method for strings. You can also write it that way. This formatting technique is more powerful and more elegant than the old % way. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#formatspec).